# Show that $H$ of part $(c)$ contains all $3-$cycles.

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

Here is the question I am trying to answer:

Show that $A_{5}$ is a simple group. Do so in the following steps:

$(a)$ Write out all partitions of $5.$ Which of these correspond exclusively to even permutations?

$(b)$ Show that $A_{5}$ is generated by $3-$cycles.

Hint: It suffices to show that every product $(a b)(c d)$ of two transpositions is a product of $3-$cycles.

$(c)$ Show that, if $H \subset A_{5}$ is a normal subgroup and $H \neq \{e\},$ then $H$ contains a $3-$cycle.

$(d)$ Show that $H$ of part $(c)$ contains all $3-$cycles.

**My question is:**

I know the proofs of $a,b,c$ but the proof of $d$ was not clear for me, so I found this proof online:

" Now, We want to show that $H$ of part $(c)$ contains all $3-$cycles.\

By all cases of letter$(c)$ above, we have that $H$ contains a $3-$cycle, say $(a,b,c).$ Let $(u v w)$ be another $3-$cycle. Define
$ g = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\
u & v & w \\ \end{pmatrix}$ then $g(abc)g^{-1} = (u v w).$ Now, distinguish between 2 cases:

1 - If $g \in A_{5}$ and given $H$ is normal subgroup of $A_{5},$ then $g(abc)g^{-1} = (u v w) \in H.$

2- If $g \notin A_{5}$ then  $g(ed) \in A_{5}$ as $A_{5}$ contains 5 letters and so $a,b,c,d,e$ are distinct. And so $g(ed)(abc)(g(ed))^{-1}  \in H.$ Which can be written as $g(abc)(ed)(ed)g^{-1} \in H.$ And hence $g(abc)g^{-1}= (u v w) \in H$ because $(ed)(ed)$ is the identity permutation."

**But I do not understand in the second case the following:**

1- Why if $g \notin A_{5}$ then  $g(ed) \in A_{5}$ ? the solution said "as $A_{5}$ contains 5 letters and so $a,b,c,d,e$ are distinct." but I do not see why this leads to that $g(ed) \in A_{5},$ could anyone explain this for me please?

2- Also, I do not understand in the second line in case 2, why $g(ed)(abc) = $g(abc)(ed),$ could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 means: If $g$ is odd then $g(ed)$ is even which is obvious by definition of odd and even.

2 is true because $(ed), (a,b,c)$ commute being disjoint cycles.

Comment: So any 2 disjoint cycles are commutative?

Comment: Yes, that is true. It can be easily checked by multiplying.

Comment: For $1-$ do you mean $g$ is an odd permutation i.e. it consists of an odd number of transposition and hence multiplying it by another transposition makes it an even permutation and hence it is in $A_{5}$?

Comment: Odd means it is a **product** of odd number of transpositions $(x,y)$. If we multiply by one more transposition the product will involve an  even number of transpositions and so it will be  an even permutation

Comment: But that will happen only if the 5 letters are distinct ..... am I correct?

Comment: No this is always true. You use the fact that you have 5 different letters when you consider the permutation $(ed)(a,b,c)$ and permute the cycles (these cycles commute).

Comment: So the justification in the online solution was nonsense regarding the letters being distinct .... am I correct?

Comment: This part of the justification is misplaced. $h=g(ed)$ is always in $A_n$ but conjugation by $g$ and by $h$ of a 3-cycle give the same result only if $e,d$ are not in the 3-cycle which is possible only if $n>4$. The point is that any two 3-cycled are conjugate in  $S_n$ (a general fact) but you need them being conjugate in the smaller group $A_n$.